# Jmeter, delay http request with many extracted urls

Tags: jmeter, httprequest, delay

i have a issue with to many calls to the server.
I have extracted several urls with the "regex extractor".
In the next step, a "http request" calls these urls by ${extractet-urls}

But all requests after the 8th url gets a error 500 response from the server.
I tried to input several timers between, before and everywhere else, but it hasn't an impact.

So my question is:
how can i delay in this single http request which calls all the extracted urls?

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the requeat you can add sampler ->Java Request. Then change classname to SleepTest and it'll wait 1 second (configurable)

Comment: i will, when i have enogh reputation ^^

Answer (score 1):

Add a [Constant Timer](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Constant_Timer) as a child of the HTTP Request sampler (see [Scoping Rules](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#scoping_rules) for details) and provide desired delay there (in milliseconds). It will cause the relevant thread to "sleep" for the defined amount of milliseconds before executing the HTTP Request. See [A Comprehensive Guide to Using JMeter Timers](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/comprehensive-guide-using-jmeter-timers) to learn more about using Timers in JMeter tests.

---

Another option could be using [Test Action](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Action) sampler to create a delay, it doesn't generate sample result so you won't see it in .jtl results file.

The final approach is depending on what you're trying to achieve and how your test is designed.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can add a Thread Group and define a ramp up time, then put the request inside this group. The ramp up time takes the startup overload too.